how to ask for a specific language in android
I want to implement the following screen

when the use clicks enter Germany word, the Germany keyboard must open, when the use clicks translation, the default keyboard must be opened. Assuming that the Germany language keyboard is installed
I know there is a work around of separating the two, into different activities and change the language. But I do not want that.
